# как вывести сколько дубликатов и их количество

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем проблема у меня есть список    `"Europe", "Europe", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "America"` и должно вывести `"Europe"2, "Africa"3  "` и все (Америка не выводится так как не имеет дубликата)

Вот что у меня выводится

```
trueAssertion faildEurope2
falseAssertion faildAfrica2
falseAssertion faildAfrica2
falseAssertion faildAfrica2
falseAssertion faildAmerica2
falseAssertion faildAfrica2
falseAssertion faildAfrica2
falseAssertion faildAfrica2
falseAssertion faildAmerica2
trueAssertion faildAfrica3
trueAssertion faildAfrica4
falseAssertion faildAmerica4
trueAssertion faildAfrica5
falseAssertion faildAmerica5
falseAssertion faildAmerica5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Вот код:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> aList = Arrays.asList("Europe", "Europe", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "America");
        int countDuplicates = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++)
            for (int j = i+1; j < aList.size(); j++) {
                if (aList.get(i).equals(aList.get(j))) {
                    countDuplicates++;
                }
                System.out.println(aList.get(i).equals(aList.get(j)) + "Assertion faild" + aList.get(j)+countDuplicates);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: перед внутренним циклом сбрасывайте `countDuplicates` (сейчас у вас там накапливается для всех проверяемых значений из внешнего цикла). Потом внутренний цикл пускай делает подсчет дубликатов, как и сейчас это делается, а после внутреннего цикла проверяйте `countDuplicates`, если реально нашлись дубликаты - выводите из число и текущее проверяемое значение из `aList.get(i)`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1280605/192901 , только ключ нужен не длина строки, а сама строка.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> aList = Arrays.asList("Europe", "Europe", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "America");
        int countDuplicates = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++)
            for (int j = i+1; j < aList.size(); j++) {
                if (aList.get(i).equals(aList.get(j))) {
                    countDuplicates++;
                    aList.remove(j);
                }
                
            }
                if(countDuplicates > 1){
                    System.out.println(aList.get(i)+" "+countDuplicates);
                    aList.remove(i);
                    countDuplicates = 1;
                }
        }

    }
```

Вроде бы так.

Answer (score -1):

Сложновата реализация, отсюда всегда все беды. Принцип кiss никто не отменял:

```
Map<String, Long> result = Arrays.asList("Europe", "Europe", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "America").stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())); 
result.entrySet().removeIf(e->e.getValue()==1);
```

Comment: просто интересно, кто это "светоч", минусующий ответы. можете предложить решение лучше? поделитесь своими гениальными идеями, просветите темноту некультурную.